# Как устроена база данных "stackoverflow.com"

Tags: база-данных

Как устроена база данных "stackoverflow.com"?

Вопрос в том:
  - содержание вопроса;
  - содержание комментария;
  - содержание ответа;
лежат в отдельных таблицах?

Или это одна таблица в которой проставляется тип записи: "вопрос", "ответ", "комментарий"?

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev а является ли это настоящей схемой настоящей БД? Или же это всего лишь красивый интерфейс для простых смертных, а настоящая БД совершенно другая?

Comment: @andreymal, это мы наверняка никогда не узнаем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84900/discussion-between--and-grundy).

Answer (score 3):

Схема база данных [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), в которой содержатся таблицы с полями, еще там есть редактор SQL, можно попробовать писать запросы сразу, для примера:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTS AS P
  LEFT JOIN COMMENTS AS C 
    ON C.PostId = P.Id;
```

[Как устроена база данных “stackoverflow.com”](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Вопросы, комментарии, ответы хранятся в разных таблицах, связаны они через внешние ключи.

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните ответ, чтобы он не был голой ссылкой.

Comment: @Yaroslav 1. Не могли бы пояснить, что делает предложенный вами запрос? 2. Как разделить `комментарии к вопросам` и `комментарии к ответам`? Пример: `Вопрос 1, id=1`,  `Ответ 1, id=1`.  Тогда получается  для `комментариев вопроса` и `комментариев ответа` внешний ключ будет "1" ? При условии если все комментарии хранятся в одной таблице

Comment: он производит выборку постов и присоединяет к ним их комментарии. Никак, они хранятся в разных таблицах!

Comment: @Yaroslav Т.е. ещё есть отдельные таблицы: 1. Таблица  `комментариев к вопросам` 2. Таблица `комментариев к ответам`. Я правильно понял?

Comment: ага, Вы правильно поняли)